# Show that $\langle\,23 \rangle\ =\langle\, 23 , \alpha-10\rangle^2 \langle\, 23, \alpha-3 \rangle$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $x^3-x-1$ and $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.
(i) Show that $\langle\,23 \rangle\ =\langle\, 23 , \alpha-10\rangle^2 \langle\, 23, \alpha-3 \rangle$
(ii) Show that $\langle\,1 \rangle\ =\langle\, 23, \alpha-10, \alpha-3 \rangle\ $

I have shown $\mathcal{O}_K=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$.
It's quite messy to simplify $\langle\, 23 , \alpha-10\rangle^2 \langle\, 23, \alpha-3 \rangle$ using $\langle a,b \rangle \langle c, d \rangle=\langle ac, bd, ad, bc \rangle$ unlike some quadratic extensions.
How do I show (i), (ii) using some theorems?

Comment: I don't think (ii) is correct, because $(23,\alpha-10,\alpha-3)\supset (23,-7)=(1)$.

Comment: True. It was indeed <1>. Thanks for catching the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the ideal prime decomposition of $23\mathcal O_K$ all you need is to factorize $x^3-x-1$ in $\mathbb{F}_{23}$. We have the following:

$$x^3-x-1 = (x-10)^2(x-3) \text{ in } \mathbb{F}_{23}$$

Hence we get $23\mathcal O_K = (23,\alpha-10)^2(23,\alpha-3)$

This result is known as the Dedekind's Theorem and you can find more about it [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/dedekindf.pdf).

For the second part, as noted in the comments we have that:

$$-7 = (\alpha - 10) -  (\alpha - 3) \in (23, \alpha-10, \alpha-3)$$
$$1 = 4\cdot23 + 13 \cdot (-7) \in (23, \alpha-10, \alpha-3)$$

Hence we get that $(1) \subseteq (23,\alpha-10)^2(23,\alpha-3)$. The other inclusion is trivial.

Comment: You are right, actually I could find the prime ideal factorization using the theorem. I'm wondering how you factorized $x^3-x-1$ in $\mathbb{F}_{23}$. Did you do it by inspection or did you use Berlekamp’s Algorithm?

Comment: @Andrew in fact I used a math engine to find th factorization. Nevertheless I feel inspection should be the way to go here. You can easily find that 3 is a root and then just apply the quadratic formula upon division by $(x-3)$

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot!